Association between maternal education and child health
I am trying to estimate the effect of maternal education on child vaccination using logistic regression. My independent variable is categorical and represents various levels education like none, primary, upper primary, secondary, higher secondary, some college. I have also used some household controls upon introduction of the household controls coefficient for upper primary becomes higher than that of college, which is counter intuitive. My data has very few college graduated mothers and much more mothers who have studied till upper primary. Can anyone help me explaining these results?

For people to provide a meaningful answer, you should include more details, e.g. the number of observations in each education category, their coefficients and significance, and the reference group. Perhaps also elaborate on why you think your current finding is counter-intuitive.

Is your independent variable something like "1 = less than high school, 2 = high school, 3 = some college, 4 = college, 5 = more than college" ?
If so, then you'll want to create dummy variables for categories and use those dummy variables rather than the one independent variable.

You need to use survey sampling weights.
